# How to access one app to another app using scrolling?

Tags: android, autoscroll

I create a android app for Auto clicker, that can be used to click the XY position of the window,The click event is done during some interval, Similar that i can implement the scrolling event.I have attached the reference link is -https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tafayor.autoscroll2&hl=en, I dont have idea of this.Give me some suggestion for auto Scrolling.

Comment: Are you trying to launch the other app ?

Comment: yes, i can access the another app

Comment: access and launch are two different things, are you trying to LAUNCH?

Comment: i can access the another app scrolling view with out using the user interface.

Comment: Try with `MotionEvent`